# C# Selenium Invalid Selector Exception

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using the Firefox add on to select the XPath of an image I want to click during my automation test using C#, and I keep running into an InvalidSelectorException Error.

Here is the XPath that was found using firefox.

```
id('ctl00_left_content')/x:div[4]/x:div[1]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[5]/x:p/x:a[2]/x:img
```

I'm using the XPath:

```
//*[@id('ctl00_left_content')/x:div[4]/x:div[1]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[5]/x:p/x:a[2]/x:img]"
```

and this returns the InvalidSelectorError

and I have tried:

```
//*[@id=('ctl00_left_content')/div[4]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/p/a[2]/img]
```

but this returns "Unable to locate element" Error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use xpath

Comment: What should I use then? ID? And how could I correct the Xpath using something else?

Comment: @CRich Can you add the relevant page source? You should have a closing bracket after the the id value part in your xpath. It is missing in your xpath.

Comment: Your all locator xpath looks incorrect. Could you share relevant HTML as well??

Comment: @Grasshopper That worked! Thank You So Much! Could you submit your comment as an Answer so I can check it as one. I don't know why it just would tell me it was an Invalid Element because i was missing a bracket, instead of saying Unable to locate. But thank you so much, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: Thank all of you guys that took the time out to try to help me also. I greatly appreciate it

Comment: @CRich Added as answer...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you add the relevant page source? 
You should have a closing bracket after the the id value part in your xpath. It is missing in your xpath.

Comment: You'd be much better adding an Id if possible. XPath selectors don't perform that well and are very brittle. Converting our test suite to ids greatly increased performance and reliability of tests